# SQL - getDate() not being saved as value for [Date] field

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm getting an exception stating "'UserReportsAdd' expects parameter '@Date', which was not supplied."

Here's the stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserReportsAdd] 
        @ID BIGINT OUTPUT,
        @Date datetime,
        @ReportingUser bigint,
        @ReportedUserID bigint,
        @Description nvarchar (2000)
    AS
    BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO UserReports (
        ReportingUser,
        ReportedUserID,
        [Description],
        [Date]
    )
        VALUES (
        @ReportingUser,
        @ReportedUserID,
        @Description,
        getDate()
    )
    END
```

Why would I be getting the error that @Date isn't be supplied when I'm defining it in the insert statement and giving it the value of getDate()?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your procedure is expecting a Date. It will throw an error at that point if no date is supplied.

Either remove the @date parameter, or supply it with a default value if you want it to be optional.

Answer (score 3):

It's listed as a parameter.  That's all the interpreter is checking at that point - there's a required parameter that's not got a value.

You can either move it out of the parameter block and declare it down below, or give it a default value in the declaration `@Date = GETDATE()`

Answer (score 0):

The code calling your Stored Procedure is not passing the `@Date` parameter. The code within your SP seems ok.

e.g:

```
declare @id bigint
declare @date datetime = getdate() -- this one is missing by the calling code
declare @reportingUser bigint = 1
declare @reportedUserId bigint = 1
declare @description nvarchar(2000) = 'some description'

exec [dbo].[UserReportsAdd] @id output, @date /* this is missing */, @reportingUser, @reportedUserId, @descripion
```